# SVN: how to retrieve from repo only files with specified mask

Tags: svn

There is a large SVN repository.
I would like to retrieve only files (many!) with (one) specified mask or with name given implicitly. There are a lot of files that meet the criteria and lay in various places in directory structure.
Is it any way to retrieve them all with their directories in simple steps?

Answer (score 0):

Here you go...

**EDIT** (from comment)
First get an empty checkout of repository

```
svn co --depth=empty URLREPO
```

then create a file `list_of_files.txt` with path of all the files which you want to update and try this...

```
svn update `cat list_of_files.txt`
```

You should keep these in mind...

- Absolute path must be specified.
- If you specify a directory, all the content will be updated.

For creating `list_of_files.txt` you can use UNIX `find` command.

Hope this helps!!!

Comment: But I don't have a local copy of repo. Repo is huge and I would like to retirieve only a tiny part of it containing interesting files.

Comment: Man but you should know the name and path of the files; you don't need to have a local copy.

Comment: You can do an empty working copy with svn co --depth=empty URLREPO. Then use the command above.

Comment: `svn co --depth empty URLREPO` and then in the repo itself `svn list --depth infinity > list_of_files.txt` which will dump all file paths from the server.